# Partial sum of infinite series

Tags: summation, partial-functions

In a probability excercise I concluded that the expected value is the following infinite series:

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{2i}{2^i}$

I wrote down the first few terms and saw that it converges to 4, however, how do I solve this properly?

Comment: @Arbuja Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: This has been asked many times, in one form or the other. Define $f$ by $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i$, for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$. What is $f(x)$, as a closed form expression? Use it to get $f'(x)$, in two ways (closed-form, and series by termwise differentiation). What is $f'(1/2)$?

Comment: @rugkei Clement C. listed a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. We note, when $|u|<1$ - that $\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum_{k \ge 0}u^k$. So, $(\frac{1}{1-u})^2=\sum_{k \ge 0}ku^{k-1}$. The $k=0$ case of the series just mentioned is of no value as $0$ times anything is zero. Hence $(\frac{1}{1-u})^2=\sum_{k \ge 1}ku^{k-1}$. Let $u=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $\sum_{k \ge 1}k\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$  is $4$. This is the same as your series, that is $\sum_{k \ge 1}k\frac{2}{2^{k}}$.